# Length of LOB data (%1) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum %2

Tags: sql-server, replication, configuration, blob

We recently hit this error shortly after enabling replication on a table.

```
Length of LOB data (%1) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum %2
```

I've found solutions to this problem already:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925824/when-insert-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536
- http://sqlmusings.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/issue-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536/

However there's no explanation of what this configuration was there for in the first place.  If we turn off the LOB size limit what side effects does that have - are we opening ourselves up to more issues in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max text repl size options exists to limit how much LOB data can be added to a replicated column.  If you turn off the LOB size limit and a user inserts a large amount of LOB data, latency will increase and replication will come to a crawl.  The max text repl size option can be used to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks Brandon - do you know of any stats around this (i.e. how replication time scales with the size of the lob), or know whether the impact will be limited to the current table vs hitting all tables on that publisher/distributor/subscriber?